# 'ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

**Note:** Please make sure to comment as to what I should mention to improve this question instead of thumbing down, I was able to successfully set up React Navigation with expo for another project, and would love to get RNN up and running in this project.

---

I'm working on setting up React Native Navigation for my React Native app, specifically iOS using Xcode.

I've changed the `AppDelegate.m` file as instructed:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

@end
```

Upon making my changes, I am receiving two Xcode errors:

```
'ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h' file not found
Use of undeclared identifier 'ReactNativeNavigation'
```

I have made sure to follow all the steps, the error is happening in the step 3 of the [React Native Navigation iOS documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=ios)

Comment: Did not understand the downvote either, so I upvoted ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing node_modules folder, then doing a fresh npm install or yarn install in your project directory.  Following that run react-native link.

Comment: No.  I'm saying just delete your node_modules folder.  Then in your project directory run: yarn install or npm install. This will reinstall all of your dependencies.  Then run: react-native link to link them to your ios project: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Comment: Ok thank you.  It took me a bit to realize what you said.  I did as you mentioned and now the error message is gone.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

it mentioned here https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing/ you might face this problem .

you have to add react native navigation pod file manual   `pod 'ReactNativeNavigation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-navigation'` to your Podfile and run `cd ios && pod install`

Comment: if you already ran `npx rnn-link` successfully, then you just need to run `cd ios && pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to update the pods after installing the package. Run `cd ios && pod install`.