# How to resolve React Native iOS linking error:: 'ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h' file not found?

Tags: ios, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-linking

I have integrated React Native Navigation package for my React Native application.I need to update my old React Native Navigation version to latest version.
I am following it's official docs for setup:: check this link https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=ios

I am facing an issue in iOS linking.

> Error:: 'ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h' file not found
>
> Error:: Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier ReactNativeNavigation

I have also followed this previous post but it's not works for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058375/reactnativenavigation-reactnativenavigation-h-file-not-found)
I'm setting up React Native Navigation for my application, for iOS using Xcode.

I've made modifications in the AppDelegate.m file as followed by it's official link:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIΩApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];
  
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue for iOS platform.

Comment: make sure that `libReactNativeNavigation.a` is included in the main projects `Link Binary With Libraries` section.

Comment: Yes, I have drag and drop it from ReactNativeNavigation.xcodeproj -> Poducts -> libReactNativeNavigation.a to Link Binary With Libraries on the right pane section. Now it's marked as required

Comment: any luck with this @ArchanaSharma

Comment: I have cleaned my project, and then removed all reference of react native navigation library and re added library again, it resolves problem for me.

Comment: You should do step 3.a on the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still having other build issues but adding the line

`pod 'ReactNativeNavigation', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/ReactNativeNavigation.podspec'`

to the Podfile in my ios directory resolved the XCode error for me. Once this line is added you have to run

`pod install` from within the ios directory

The react-native-navigation documentation says that new versions of react-native will use pods. You can this see it under the **Installation with CocoaPods** section

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your podfile

```
pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
```

And then import the file with:

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
```